# How does my if statment react to streaming data when using an API

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, if-statement, boolean-logic

Lets say, for example, I'm working with an auction api. I have a subscribe function that i can use to get realtime data on the potential buyers name and what their repective bids are.

I have a hard time getting functions to execute only once inside the "if statments" when there is alot happening on the subscribe channel (auctionAPI.subscribe).

If the name Mike comes up twice within a short amount of time, the first "if statment" executes twice. I understand that all of the code that i put inside the auctionAPI.subscribe will execute when the API sends data but why is the primitive booleans not working?

```
let value = 1;

auctionAPI.subscribe((data) => {

  if (value === 1) {
    if (data.Name == "Mike" && data.price >= 300) {
      //do something
      value = 2
    }
  }
  if (value === 2) {
    if (data.Name == "Charlotte" && data.price >= 1000) {
      //do something
      value = 3
    }
  }

});
```

Comment: Use "var" instead of "let" for value because "let" is Block scope and second If Statement never happend

Answer (score 0):

The example code as it stands seems like it should work fine. I would say be wary that you aren't mistakenly redefining 'value' with 'let' anywhere inside of the subscribe handler as this would in fact re-scope and cause it to not effect the outer 'value'.

I know it is not exactly what was asked, but if are looking to throttle the handling of calls, something like this would do as such. It would throttle handling the calls to a maximum of once every 500ms per 'Name' (hopefully this is a unique key)

```js
//Just some setup code to call the delegate
let auctionAPI = {
    subscribe: (delegate) => {
    //Quick subsequent calls
    delegate({ Name: 'A Name', price: 100 });
    delegate({ Name: 'A Name', price: 300 });
    delegate({ Name: 'A Name', price: 200 });
    setTimeout(() => {
        //Wait a second and quick subsequent calls
        delegate({ Name: 'A Name', price: 600 });
        delegate({ Name: 'A Name', price: 500 });
        delegate({ Name: 'A Name', price: 300 });
    }, 1000);
  }
};

function doSomething(data) {
  //Where you want to acutally do the real logic with the throttled calls
  console.log(`Do something with ${JSON.stringify(data)}`);
}

let scheduled = {};
function throttleByName (data) {
  if (scheduled[data.Name]) {
    //Already scheduled to process
    //-Make sure to use the latest data
    //-Could be modified to keep the larger value
    scheduled[data.Name].data = data;
  } else {
    scheduled[data.Name] = {
      data: data,
      timerId: setTimeout(() => {
        let scheduledData = scheduled[data.Name].data;
        delete scheduled[data.Name];
        doSomething(scheduledData);
      }, 500)
    };
  }
}

auctionAPI.subscribe(throttleByName);
```

Comment: Not what was asked but exactly what I was looking for. That's great, Thank you very much! So if i understand the code correctly; If the API sends several calls with the same data.name within a shorter amount of time than the timerId, setTimeout. I only get the first call with the corresponding data.name.

Comment: All that is true, except,  the way I provided it, you would get the last call given to you. (Assuming the latest value would be the most important one?) However that could easily be changed to process whichever you think makes sense. (eg. First Value / Last Value / Smallest Value / Greatest Value)